# Struggle with OSGi dependencies for Pellet and OWL-API

Tags: java, maven, osgi, owl, pellet

I wrote a facade for the owl-api paired with the pellet reasoner to easily access an ontology. It worked quiet well. Then I tried to pack it as an OSGi Bundle and use it via an TrackerService from other services. The owl-api bundle needs guava and trove to run. For trove there is no bundle. Even after reloading the target platform, the pellet jars were not recognized as bundle in eclipse (I took them from jpm4j). So I thought about just take all the jar- stuff and squeeze it into the bundle.

I read a lot of how-to's for packaging third-party jars with a bundle. I use the maven-bundle-plugin and after reading some [documentation](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format) from this plugin and bndtools I decided to use **conditional-package**, because [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/felix-users/201410.mbox/%3CetPan.544a7d80.74b0dc51.1d24@Endofunctor.local%3E) it was described that all entries in the pom are passed to the bndtools. After the compilation, no jar was packaged with my bundle :(. Then I used **embed-dependencies**. It didnt't work because the transient dependiencies were not available at runtime. So I used the **embed-transient** tag (I already read that this is bad style). The Import-Package part was filled automatically with all transient dependencies, so I overwrote it by hand to ged rid of the errors regarding the unsolved imports. This worked and I was able to use the owl-api to insert new properties,individuals, etc (yeah).

When I tryed to start the pellet reasoner, I got the error message below at runtime. I think it is about the dependency-mess in my project again. I already know that the current way is the wrong one, but I was not able to find a better one. Please help me to get this dependency management in OSGi right.

Cheers,
Stephan

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
!ENTRY org.apache.felix.configadmin 4 0 2015-11-16 11:28:45.218
!MESSAGE [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=28, bundle=7/initial@reference:file:..vdg.iCar.service]: Unexpected problem updating configuration vdg.iCar.service
!STACK 0
java.lang.Error: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider for class javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory cannot be found
at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:892)
at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:140)
at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseFloat(DatatypeConverter.java:243)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.types.floating.XSDFloat.getValue(XSDFloat.java:81)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.types.floating.XSDFloat.getCanonicalRepresentation(XSDFloat.java:58)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.DatatypeReasonerImpl.getCanonicalRepresentation(DatatypeReasonerImpl.java:365)
at org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.createLiteral(ABox.java:1746)
at org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.addLiteral(ABox.java:1725)
at org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.addPropertyValue(KnowledgeBase.java:974)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletVisitor.visit(PelletVisitor.java:1103)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiomImpl.accept(OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiomImpl.java:119)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletVisitor.visit(PelletVisitor.java:699)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyImpl.accept(OWLOntologyImpl.java:1516)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner.refresh(PelletReasoner.java:967)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner.<init>(PelletReasoner.java:345)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner.<init>(PelletReasoner.java:304)
at com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasonerFactory.createReasoner(PelletReasonerFactory.java:71)
at de.dlr.vdg.ontology.osgi.impl.util.ReasonerUtil.getInferredOntology(ReasonerUtil.java:56)
at de.dlr.vdg.ontology.osgi.impl.util.ReasonerUtil.getInferredRelations(ReasonerUtil.java:304)
at de.dlr.vdg.ontology.osgi.impl.OntologyServiceImpl.startReasoning(OntologyServiceImpl.java:106)
at de.dlr.vdg.iCar.osgi.impl.iCarServiceImpl.start(iCarServiceImpl.java:67)
at de.dlr.vdg.iCar.osgi.Activator.updated(Activator.java:65)
at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updated(ManagedServiceTracker.java:189)
at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updateService(ManagedServiceTracker.java:152)
at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceTracker.java:85)
at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1444)
at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1400)
at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider for class javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory cannot be found
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:304)
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:268)
at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:145)
at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:890)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:297)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:292)
... 31 more
```

POM-File (important parts):

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                <instructions>
                    <Private-Package>${bundle.namespace}.*</Private-Package>
                    <Export-Package>${bundle.namespaceShared}</Export-Package>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Bundle-Activator>${bundle.namespace}.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>JavaSE-1.8</Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework;version="[1.6,2)",org.osgi.se
                    rvice.cm;version="[1.4,2)",org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)"</Import-Package>
                    <Bundle-ClassPath>.,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ansell.pellet</groupId>
        <artifactId>pellet-owlapiv3</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6-ansell</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ansell.pellet</groupId>
        <artifactId>pellet-query</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6-ansell</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

After an additional day of research I came across [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1626292?start=0) at oracle.

The pellet-api references the xerces and xml-api libs and due to the transient inclusion of dependencies, these libs were included in my bundle. But these libs are already present in the java runtime environment. Therefore I excluded them in the **Embed-Dependency** section and everything works.

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false;groupId=!xml-apis|xerces</Embed-Dependency>
```